# android version code change is a must or not

Tags: android

My application is not submitted in Play store. Its a non market app, each time when we give an update, the application checks by its own and will download the latest build from our own server.

I have released application to my clients, for around 4 times. Each time i have
increased the version code from 1 to 4.

In my latest build i have not incremented the version code to be as 5, now i am getting a complaint from my client side that the new update is not able to be installed.

Whereas when i tried in my local device, its working good.

Does the version code affects the installation of updating a build

Comment: "the application checks by its own and will download the latest build from our own server" HOW please? what's your strategy for doing that?!

Comment: when app gets opened i will check the version name in my server, the current build version name and version name in my server gets differed the download of new build will start

Comment: i am checking only version name

Comment: `complaint from my client side that the new update is not able to be installed` does that mean the installation prcess starts, then they got some errors? or they never start download/update? AFAIK, version is needed in market to compare with installed version on mobile, so it will inform the users that there is a newer version to be installed, but trying to install another APK with the same version-name or version-code should not cause any problem.

Comment: p.s: when uploading an update into market, it will not allow upload until version-code is greater than current APK version-code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly, version code effects the market build.

Comment: if you cant get error or you can check manully another device to check your app and if you can't get error then i think your client device may be something wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to you, your code is checking on your server of a possible update via version of the app. As you have not incremented the version of the app this time, there is possible chance of error. Rest all depends upon your code. As far as google play is considered, you have to increment the version code each time you upload a new apk